# I want to get the generic dictionary as return value of function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, generics, dictionary

I want to get the generic dictionary as return value of function in vb.net.

How can I get this?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim buttons As Dictionary(Of Integer, Button) = generateControls(Of Button)(3)
    Dim textBoxes As Dictionary(Of Integer, TextBox) = generateControls(Of TextBox)(3)

End Sub

Private Function generateControls(Of T)(repeat As Integer) As Dictionary(Of Integer, T)
    Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of Integer, T)

    For i As Integer = 0 To repeat - 1
        Dim control As New T
        dic.Add(i, control)
    Next
    Return dic

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a type constraint declaring that the type has a default constructor.

Use `generateControls(Of T As New)` instead of `generateControls(Of T)`

However I prefer:

```
    Dim result = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).
                            ToDictionary(Function(i) i, Function(i) New TextBox() With {... })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I want.

Comment: Your preference is new to me. I have seen the codes like this in Python. I don't know it is possible in C#. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @jeonggu. If this has solved your problem then please tick the answer as accepted.